# Why does scrapy gives 404 for images that are available?

Tags: image, scrapy

This is an example for an image that I add to the image_urls field.
http://static.zara.net/photos//2014/I/0/2/p/5875/309/800/2/w/1920/5875309800_1_1_1.jpg
Yet I get this warning and the image is not uploaded.

[zara_com] WARNING: File (code: 404): Error downloading image from http://static.zara.net/photos//2014/I/0/2/p/5875/309/800/2/w/1920/5875309800_1_1_1.jpg> referred in

Though an image like this one:
http://static.zara.net/photos//2014/V/1/3/p/1280/303/105/2/w/1920/1280303105_2_1_1.jpg
is uploaded normally.

What might be the problem? what should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, they seem to be filtering requests made with the default scrapy user agent:

```
'User-Agent': 'Scrapy/0.24.2 (+http://scrapy.org)'
```

When I changed the USER_AGENT setting in settings.py of my project, it started returning 200 on all requests. The strange thing is that before that it returned 404 even on the image, which you said is returned normally.

P.S. It's not very good to scrape content from a site, if they are not allowing it, but well it's not like they are disallowing it in their robots.txt. Still you should probably enable the RobotsTxtMiddleware and the AutoThrottle extension to ensure you are playing fairly.